# Get last X files created from a directory (PHP)

Tags: php, file, sorting, directory

Im using this code to get the most recent file created:

```
<?php 

    $files = glob($siteRoot.'/dir/*/*.php');
    $files = array_combine($files, array_map('filectime', $files));
    arsort($files);
    echo key($files); 

?>
```

How can I enhance this to get the last 3 files created, or what ever number I need? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just take an [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) from your array:

```
$slice = array_slice($files, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

To go along with @Rizier123's excellent answer, you don't need to change the array to sort it:

```
$files = glob($siteRoot.'/dir/*/*.php');
array_multisort(array_map('filectime', $files), SORT_DESC, $files);
$newest = array_slice($files, 0, 3);
```

Comment: Also very helpful insight. Thanks!